# Swing: Placing group of components in a frame

Tags: swing, layout, grouping, jcomponent

To be accurate and brief:
Is it possible to Layout a frame container with group of components(like check boxes, radio buttons, etc...) instead of adding them one by one to a frame? So, positioning them in a frame would be a lot more easier.

```
private void initializaUI(){
    setSize(700, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //Panel container to wrap checkboxes and radio buttons
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
    JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(panel, defaultCloseOperation, null));
    JPanel radioPanel_1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
    JPanel radioPanel_2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

    //Text field to display order
    JTextField orderField = new JTextField(20);
    orderField.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 20);

    //Button to process place the order
    JButton button = new JButton("Process Selection");
    button.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 40);

    //toppings check boxes
    checkBoxPanel.setVisible(true);
    checkBoxPanel.setBounds(100, 200, 100, 50);
    String Topping[] = {"Tomato", "Green Pepper", "Black Olives", "Mushrooms", "Extra Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Sausage"};
    checkBoxPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Tomato"));
    checkBoxPanel.add(new JCheckBox(Topping[1]));
    checkBoxPanel.add(new JCheckBox(Topping[2]));
    checkBoxPanel.add(new JCheckBox(Topping[3]));
    checkBoxPanel.add(new JCheckBox(Topping[4]));
    checkBoxPanel.add(new JCheckBox(Topping[5]));
    checkBoxPanel.add(new JCheckBox(Topping[6]));       
    //sizes radio buttons
    String size[] = {"Small:$6.50", "Medium:$8.50", "Large:$10.00"};
    JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton(size[0]);
    radio.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 20);
    //  
    panel.add(checkBoxPanel);
    //
    setContentPane(panel);
```

This is the code which supposed to perform some actions based on user entry. please help me make it clear and readable.
This is the error: "The field Component.x is not visible"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's what a [`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) is for. It's an empty container that has its inner layout manager and that can be placed wherever you want inside a `JFrame` (or inside another `JPanel`). So, just to give you an example you can have:

```
JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(..));
JPanel fieldsPanel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(..));

checkBoxPanel.add(new JCheckBox(..));

fieldsPanel.add(new JTextField(..));

frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(checkBoxPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(..)
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, So the let's put it this way: whatever checkboxes could be added in a group; then the created group could be added into a Panel; at the end the Panel will be added to a root Panel or a frame.

Comment: so were you talking about the `ButtonGroup`?

Comment: Kinda of, I intend to group couple of checkboxes and radioboxes then move place them in an empty panel to place them all in a frame after all.

Comment: Yes I meant if you talked about the class `ButtonGroup` when you wrote about _with group of components_. Because `ButtonGroup` is meant to be a logical grouping, that's why you need to manually add them to the interface anyway.

Comment: I've updated my question posting the code snippet, Please help me find my problem as I'm stuck somewhere in the beginning! eclipse throws an invisibility error of the checkBoxPanel.

Comment: @mehdix_: first thing I notice is that the first argument of the BoxLayout constructor is not the panel on which you are defining the layout. Try with `Panel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel(); checkBoxPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(checkBoxPanel, ...));`. Then you could slim many operations by using loops (like for to iterate over arrays instead that creating every check box one by one.